# Are there any scenarios where IIS logging gets disabled automatically e.g. low disk space

Tags: iis-7

I have a website for which IIS logs were enabled. They seem to have been **disabled automatically** as none of my team members have disabled it (At least that is what they said!). The day this happened, we had run into **low disk space** problem in our server.
I tried searching on google but could not find something concrete which links these 2 events. Can anyone please shed some light on this.

Comment: So logging is now disabled on the server level? If so I would look through the various versions of `applicationHost.config` in `C:\inetpub\history` and see when the value for `<httpLogging dontLog="true" />` was changed. Maybe comparing that time with other Windows events can give you and idea. I don't think it is automatically disabled, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this once and see, If it happens again.

Referred : http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile

> HOW TO CONFIGURE FLUSHING A W3C LOG BY ENTRY COUNT
>
> 1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:
>
>    - If you are using Windows Server 2012 R2:
>           On the taskbar, click Server Manager, click Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
>    - If you are using Windows 8.1:
>
>      - Hold down the Windows key, press the letter X, and then click Control Panel.
>
>        - Click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
>
> 2.In the Connections pane, select the server, and then double-click Configuration Editor.
>
> 3.In the Configuration Editor, for the Section, expand system.applicationHost, and then select sites.
>
> 4.Expand siteDefaults, and then expand logFile.
>
> 5.For flushByEntryCountW3Clog, enter the number of events to be stored in the buffer before they are flushed to the log file.
>
> 6.In the Action pane, click Apply.